# In Ohm's Law, why do we not take the constant of proportionality as $\dfrac{1}{R}$?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

This is the standard derivation for *Ohm's Law* :

$$I \propto V$$
$$V \propto I$$
$$\therefore V = k.I$$

> Where $k$ is the constant of proportionality.
>
> We define this $k$ as resistance of $R$.

Why can't we derive it like this:
$$I \propto V$$
$$\therefore I = k_2V$$

> Where $k_2$ is the constant of proportionality

So, in this case : $$k_2=\dfrac{1}{R}$$

Why was resistance not defined as how $k_2$ is defined and why was it defined as it is?

I actually think that this might be the reason :

Most of the time, *current*(($I$) is less than the *voltage*($V$)

Let's say that *resistance* was defined as $k_2$, in that case, $$k_2=\dfrac{I}{V}$$ if $I$ is less than $V$ (like it generally is), then the value of $k_2$ will come out to be a fraction which is not too convenient. So, if we define the constant of proportionality as $R$, then $$R=\dfrac{V}{I}$$ and since $I$ is less than $V$ in most cases, we would get $R > 0$ unlike the case with $k_2$ in which we would get $0 <k_2 < 1$

Is this reasonable?

Comment: How can current be less or more than voltage? They are different things. That's like saying I can run faster than the volume of my water bottle.

Comment: @AaronStevens What I was comparing was **magnitude** of current and voltage

Comment: Yeah, that still doesn't work. Magnitudes have units also.

Comment: I thought magnitude is a pure number. Like if we say $1$ $ampere$, the magnitude is $1$ and the unit is $amperes$.

Comment: I think what you're getting at is that in a typical bench-top electronics circuit, the voltage (measured in Volts, e.g., 5V) is usually larger than the current (measured in Amps, e.g. 0.1A), so that the Resistance (measured in Ohms) is a biggish number (e.g., 50$\Omega$). Of course, this depends on the application. When you're starting your car, the 12V from the battery is a smaller number than the few hundred Amps that flow (which implies a resistance of a small fraction of an Ohm).

Comment: @OscarBravo Exactly

Comment: But our choice of units is arbitrary. 1 amp is 1000 milliamps. So is 1000 mA more or less than 5 V? It would also be just as valid to make up a new current unit called the Rajdeep, such that $1\ {\rm A}=5.2\times 10^6\ {\rm Rd}$. Now is 5.2 million Rd more or less than 5 V?

Comment: @ThePhoton Of course the units are arbitrary and you could make any units you like. The point the OP is making is that the _actual units we use_, Volts and Amps, happen to have typical values in benchtop electronics that lead to _resistance_ values (in Ohms) that are big numbers (http://www.resistorguide.com/resistor-values/). He was wondering about using the inverse (conductance) instead. Don't know why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are talking about is [conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance). You can use that instead if you want to.

> I actually think that this might be the reason :
>   Most of the time, current(I) is less than the voltage(V)

This isn't correct. You can't compare values that are physically different. Currents can't be more or less than voltages.

> ...then the value of $k_2$ will come out to be a fraction which is not too convenient

I'm not sure where this is coming from. Fractions are totally fine. Beginners in algebra might hate fractions, but they aren't inconvenient in their actual application. Plus, many numbers that are fractions have reciprocals that are also fractions. e.g. $3/2$ and $2/3$.

---

> Is this reasonable?

To summarize, it's totally fine to use $1/R$ which is the conductance. However, your arguments as to why one would want to do this either aren't valid, or are nonissues.

Comment: Let's say that you are George Ohm, and you notice a relationship between current and voltage. How would you decide which constant to call *resistance* and  which one to call *conductance*? This is probably a silly question

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu The larger the Resistance for a given voltage, the smaller the current. Hence "resistance" resists current. A larger conductance (smaller resistance) means you can *conduct* more current. I think that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized how stupid my arguments were. And by the way, when I said *fractions*, I was actually referring to proper fractions ($0 < x < 1$ or $\dfrac{p}{q}$, where $p < q$)

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu Proper fractions aren't inconvenient either :)

Comment: And as I said, I know my arguments were stupid and childish. Also, I'm no beginner to algebra too. :)

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu Yeah sorry I wasn't trying to say you were. I was just speaking in general from my experience in tutoring.

Comment: I didn't get a bit offended. I was just making it clear :). Also, please check out my comment on the original post about magnitudes having units.